# Transit visa Kyrgyzstan

Tags: visas, transit, kyrgyzstan

I am an Indian passport holder and we are travelling from Istanbul to Delhi  (India) via Bishkek (Kyrgyzstan ) on September 30, 2017 by Pegasus Air and we have a 3 hour transit waiting at Bishkek (Kyrgyzstan) Airport for a connecting flight. In this case, do I need transit visa in Kyrgyzstan or not?

Comment: Ken. Thank you for your comment .but are you sure I do not need transit visa becs if need visa I have to lost 600 $.

Comment: If you're uncertain, you can use [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/) search tool (anyone can use it, not just its passengers), or check directly with the [Kyrgyz Embassy](http://www.kgzembind.in/) in India. Here, you're asking random strangers on the internet; an official source may be more reassuring.

Answer (score 9):

According to Timatic (the standard visa and travel restriction database used by airlines), you do ***not*** need a transit visa for Kyrgyzstan when transiting as an Indian passport holder.